# How can I dynamically align Widgets in a Row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a widget that consists of a `Row()` with `MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`, and has three `IconButton` as children.

The third button uses a bool `showButton` in a ternary operator to toggle whether the third button is displayed or not.

My issue is when the button is not being displayed, the Row spacing still accounts for the empty Container (as seen in the pics at the bottom).

Besides creating two separate Rows with two and three buttons (to toggle between) is there a better method for spacing these buttons, or is there an alternative to an empty Container that won't take up space in my alignment?

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {...},
      icon: Icon(...),
    ),
      IconButton(
      onPressed: () {...},
      icon: Icon(...),
    ),
    showButton
        ? Container()
        :  IconButton(
      onPressed: () {...},
      icon: Icon(...),
    ), 
  ],
),
```

[image: 3 buttons]

[image: 2 buttons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using ternary operator to show an empty `Container` when the condition is false, you can conditionally include the item in the list by doing this:

```dart
children: [
  // ...
  if (showButton) IconButton(...),
]
```